# Trigger scroll to roll down to bottom automatically in Mendix Native Mobile App

Tags: mobile, native, react-native-scrollview, mendix

I’m working on a **Native** Mobile App, which is being built inside the **Mendix** Platform. And I'm trying to figure out how to trigger a *scroll-to-bottom* behavior automatically.

My situation is:

I have a form with a lot of fields, and some with conditional visibility. Which means that they will appear if the user selects some specific options, in radio-buttons.
But some of them will be out of the visible area when the user clicks the related radio-button, and the field becomes visible (as it is located at the bottom of the form).

I trying to find a way to force the scroll to the bottom when these new fields become visible (from the user click in radio-button above).

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the Mendix market place there is a native widget that seems to be able to do what you need to achieve: https://marketplace.mendix.com/link/component/116738
The last update was in May this year for Mendix 9.1 and there is a version for Mendix 8.17 as well.
Hope this provides a solution.